# Silverlight: How to route mouse events from one control to another?

Tags: silverlight, events, mouse

If I catch mouse move/mouse button down events in one control, how do I route the caught event to another control?

In MSDIN documentation I found WPF `UIElement.RaiseEvent` but it seems it doesn't exist in Silverlight.

The reason for this question is the following issue.

I have an application where user is able to pick a control on the screen to retrieve control's ID (a custom property). While user picks a control, I don't want default actions of the control to be triggered - no button clicks, no text highlighting, no link navigation etc. That's why when entering the "picking mode", I put a transparent overlay over my application and after user clicks on it I find the element behind the overlay, get its ID and remove the overlay.

This approach is working fine except one scenario when there is a scroll viewer on the screen and user might want to pick an element which is scrolled out of view. Thus when picking elements, user at first clicks on a scrollbar to scroll the required element into view, but the scrollbar doesn't work because its behind the overlay.

Currently I have working code which detects if the element under mouse cursor (and behind the overlay) is a scrollbar instance, and thus I ignore it for my picking process - my application doesn't require picking scrollbars. But how do I pass the mouse event from the overlay to the scrollbar behind?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't route the mouse events.
But what you can do is: as long as the mouse is hovered over a `Scrollbar` you can set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of your mouseClick catcher overlay to false. The click will just go through it. Or can you only detect the Scrollbar the moment the user clicks?

Comment: Yes, i had that idea but when I hide the overlay or make it IsHitTestVisible=false, then I can't detect the moment when user moves his mouse away from the scrollbar.

Comment: @Martin : hm, so even when you are not collapsing the overlay, just setting hitTest to false, you cannot get MouseMove events?

Comment: Yes. I tried to set it back to true in MouseMove, but after I have once set IsHitTestVisible=false, the overlay stops receiving mouse events at all, thus I cannot reenable it at the moment when user stops scrolling and wants to pick an element.